# How to pass boolean default value in router?

Tags: symfony

Let's say I have a history portal and I got something like this in my router: 
`article/{century}/{decade}/{year}/{month}/{day}`
The problem is that my controller have boolean default values for all these variables (false), because the business logic should decide what to show without specifying a date.
How can I do this without specifying multiple routes for this?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to specify multiple routes? Routes are cheap and will reduce your margin of error for complex requirements like this.

Comment: because i have a "paginator" in twig and it sucks to if else/if 5 cases to put two links...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>  * @Route("article/{century}/{decade}/...", defaults={"century"="false", "decade"="false", ...})
> ```

Comment: i use XML and it doesn't work like this, tried :S it says no route matched.